# Motivation for sparse vs dense matrices in Eigen

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen

Eigen provides methods for both sparse matrices in `Eigen/Sparse` and dense matrices in `Eigen/Dennse`.

My questions are:

1. What is the motivation for the `Sparse` module? My feeling is that saving a sparse matrix in a sparse form can save space and avoid useless computations for very large matrices. Are there more reasons?
2. Are the underlying algorithms the same for both dense and sparse matrices? For example, the algorithm to calculate a singular value decomposition of a matrix.
3. Does Eigen try to identify special types of a sparse matrix, for example band diagonal, and apply specialized algorithms?

Comment: This question is to broad for this site (IMO). I recommend to read through the sparse chapters of the Eigen documentation: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Sparse__chapter.html

Comment: thanks, @chtz. I was too lazy to read their documentation. ok. I guess I need to read it myself.